# Duplicate row creation and replace the cell value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a CSV file which contains the below data:

```
  NAME    | AGE  | COLLEGE  | BRANCH  | Qualification
------------------------------------------------------- 
  sai     | 21   |   FG     |   CSE   |   B.Tech
  Kiran   | 22   |   FG     |   EEE   |   M.Tech
  Anil    | 21   |   FG     |   CSE   |   B.Tech
  Ram     | 22   |   KL     |   EEE   |   B.Tech
```

**Code that I have used to create the CSV file:**

```
import pandas as pd

Name=['sai', 'Kiran', 'Anil', 'Ramj']
Age=[21, 22, 21, 22]
college=['FG', 'FG', 'FG', 'KL']
branch=['CSE', 'EEE', 'CSE', 'EEE']
Qualification=['B.Tech', 'M.Tech', 'B.Tech', 'B.Tech']

dict = {'NAME': Name, 'AGE': Age, 'COLLEGE': college, 'BRANCH': branch, 
'Qualification': Qualification }  

df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
df.to_csv('TESTINGFILE.csv',index=False)
```

**Need to implement following steps:**

---

***STEP 1:***

Based on a condition I need to create an duplicate row.

**Condition : COLLEGE = FG and BRANCH = CSE**

If the condition is satisfied then a duplicate row should be created with the BRANCH name as ECE.

```
  NAME    | AGE  | COLLEGE  | BRANCH  | Qualification
------------------------------------------------------- 
  sai     | 21   |   FG     |   CSE   |   B.Tech
  sai     | 21   |   FG     |   ECE   |   B.Tech
  Kiran   | 22   |   FG     |   EEE   |   M.Tech
  Anil    | 21   |   FG     |   CSE   |   B.Tech
  Anil    | 21   |   FG     |   ECE   |   B.Tech
  Ram     | 22   |   KL     |   EEE   |   B.Tech
```

**STEP 2:**

Now with the same condition(**COLLEGE = FG and BRANCH = CSE**), if this satisfies then change the branch from CSE to IT.

**Final Expected output:**

```
  NAME    | AGE  | COLLEGE  | BRANCH  | Qualification
------------------------------------------------------- 
  sai     | 21   |   FG     |   IT    |   B.Tech
  sai     | 21   |   FG     |   ECE   |   B.Tech
  Kiran   | 22   |   FG     |   EEE   |   M.Tech
  Anil    | 21   |   FG     |   IT    |   B.Tech
  Anil    | 21   |   FG     |   ECE   |   B.Tech
  Ram     | 22   |   KL     |   EEE   |   B.Tech
```

***Can someone help me in doing this by writing the code using pandas.***

***Thanks for the help!***

Comment: why did the first row not duplicate? College = FC and Branc = CSE there aswell.

Comment: As the condition is satisfied by first row, then the row is created, which is duplicate but the branch name is ECE instead of CSE.

Comment: Then why is the duplicate of `Anil` in the step 1 CSE?

Comment: Thanks @Erfan. Thats a mistake by me. I have edited that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create mask by conditions, replace value by `mask`, duplicated rows with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and assign value by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html), last [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
mask = (df.COLLEGE == 'FG') & (df.BRANCH == 'CSE')
df.loc[mask, 'BRANCH'] = 'IT' 
df = pd.concat([df, df[mask].assign(BRANCH='ECE')]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    NAME  AGE COLLEGE BRANCH Qualification
0    sai   21      FG     IT        B.Tech
1    sai   21      FG    ECE        B.Tech
2  Kiran   22      FG    EEE        M.Tech
3   Anil   21      FG     IT        B.Tech
4   Anil   21      FG    ECE        B.Tech
5   Ramj   22      KL    EEE        B.Tech
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the following:
1. Create a subset first by filtering
2. Change the values to `ECE`
3. Concat the dataframes together
4. Use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally change the values to `IT`

```
df_dup = df[(df.COLLEGE== 'FG') & (df.BRANCH == 'CSE')]
df_dup['BRANCH'] = 'ECE'

df = pd.concat([df, df_dup])

df['BRANCH'] = np.where((df.COLLEGE== 'FG') & (df.BRANCH == 'ECE'), 'IT', df.BRANCH)

df = df.sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
    NAME  AGE COLLEGE BRANCH Qualification
0    sai   21      FG    CSE        B.Tech
1    sai   21      FG     IT        B.Tech
2  Kiran   22      FG    EEE        M.Tech
3   Anil   21      FG    CSE        B.Tech
4   Anil   21      FG     IT        B.Tech
5   Ramj   22      KL    EEE        B.Tech
```